# Computing $G^3$ from a group $G^n$

Tags: group-theory

Let G be the symmetric group $S_3$. For For $n\in\Bbb N$, let $G^n=\{x^n : x\in G\}$.

How would I go about computing $G^3$?

Answer (score 1):

Given $S_3=\{e,(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}$ we have $(S_3)^ 3=\{e,(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),e,e\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetric group $S_3$ consists of all the permutations of $X=\{1,2,3\}$ which is normally written as product of disjoint cycles.

For example, one of the element in $S_3$ would be $f:X\rightarrow X$ where $f(1)=2,f(2)=3,f(3)=1$, which is normally written as $(1,2,3)$.

In $S_3$, the operation defined is function composition. Hence $f^3=f\circ f\circ f$. You can check the $f^3(1)=1,f^3(2)=2,f^3(3)=3$. So $f^3$ is the identity function, which is also the identity element of $S_3$. For the other case you can compute in the similar way.